# Parameter binding using GQL in Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, binding, gql

Okay so I have this mode:

```
class Posts(db.Model):
  rand1 = db.FloatProperty()
  #other models here
```

and this controller:

```
class Random(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):    
      rand2 = random.random()
      posts_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE rand1 > :rand2 ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1")
      #Assigning values for Django templating
      template_values = {
          'posts_query': posts_query,
           #test purposes
          'rand2': rand2,
          }

      path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/random.html')
      self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

So when an entity is added a random float is generated (0-1) and then when I need to grab a random entity I want to be able to just use a simple SELECT query. It errors with:

```
BadArgumentError('Missing named arguments for bind, requires argument rand2',)
```

Now this works if I go:

```
posts_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE rand1 > 1 ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1")
```

So clearly my query is wrong; how does one use a variable in a where statement :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute:

```
 "...WHERE rand1 > :rand2 ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1")
```

with:

```
  "...WHERE rand1 > :rand2 ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1", rand2=rand2)
```

Or

```
  "...WHERE rand1 > :1 ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1", rand2)
```

See for more information: "[The Gql query class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html)"

<sub>The funny thing is that I have just learned this about 2 hrs ago :P</sub>

Comment: Yay, thanks - that's fixed it :P Though it's actually:

WHERE rand1 > :1 ORDER BY rand1 LIMIT 1", rand2)

I accidentally had 'rand' instead of 'rand1', incase others were wondering and needed help.